# Why does my website start out as zoomed in on my clients screen?

Tags: css, angular

He said his resolution is 1920x1080. The website starts out as extremely zoomed in, even if the browser zoom is at 100%. When he zooms out to 67%, the website looks ok. I have really installed bootstrap, but is that necessary?

I already added:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I also added breakpoints to my code:

```
@media only screen and 
(min-device-width : 1680px) and 
(max-device-width : 1920px) { /* some css code here */ }
```

But I haven't done the smaller screens yet.

Here's the website in question made in angular: https://landau.vercel.app/

Here's a video of the said bug: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntx-CAzhB7M

Here's some additional css code :

```
.home-page {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 93px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    box-sizing: border-box;  
}

.background {
    background-image: url('/assets/images/home/Home-bg.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.about-dr-alex {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Novecento sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    top: 350px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.about-dr-alex:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.person {
    position: absolute;
    left: 190px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 900;
    height: 90%;
}

.headline {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Novecento sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 400px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    letter-spacing: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 500;
}

.barcode {
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    bottom: 50px;
    width: 200px;
}

.specialist-plastic-surgeon {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: 'Novecento sans', sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: 140px;
    right: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    line-height:40px;
}

.crafting-individual,
.solutions {
    position: absolute;
    font: normal normal 300 35px/60px 'acumin-pro';
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #ACB7BB;
}

.crafting-individual-solutions:active .crafting-individual ,
.crafting-individual-solutions:active .solutions:active {
    background-color: #D07651;
}

.crafting-individual {
    right: 40px;
    top: 300px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

.solutions {
    right: 40px;
    top: 370px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

.crafting-individual-solutions:hover .crafting-individual,
.crafting-individual-solutions:hover .solutions {
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    transition: all 1000ms;
}

.global-network-of-expertise>a,
.global-network-of-expertise>a:active,
.global-network-of-expertise>a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font: normal normal bold 35px/40px 'acumin-pro';
    text-align: right;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    right: 40px;
    top: 450px;
}

.of-expertise {
    display: block;
    font: normal normal bold 30px/42px 'acumin-pro';
    letter-spacing: 0.9px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.areas-of-expertise>a,
.areas-of-expertise>a:active,
.areas-of-expertise>a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font: normal normal 300 35px/40px 'acumin-pro';
    text-align: right;
    letter-spacing: 1.6px;
    right: 40px;
    top: 600px;
}

.areas-of-expertise>a:hover {
    letter-spacing: 2.5px;
}

.commitment-and-family {
    position: absolute;
    width: 230px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 670px;
    right: 40px;
}

.commitment-and-family>a,
.commitment-and-family>a:active,
.commitment-and-family>a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: right;
}

.commitment-and-family>a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.commitment-and-family:hover .commitment,
.commitment-and-family:hover .and,
.commitment-and-family:hover .family {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.commitment {
    position: absolute;
    color: #D07651;
    font: normal normal bold 30px/42px 'acumin-pro';
    letter-spacing: 0.9px;
    right: 0px;
}

.and {
    position: absolute;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font: normal normal bold 80px/112px 'acumin-pro';
    bottom: 0px;
}

.family {
    position: absolute;
    font: normal normal normal 50px/70px 'acumin-pro';
    color: #ACB7BB;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 7px;
}

@media only screen and 
(min-device-width : 1680px) and 
(max-device-width : 1920px) {
    .person {
        height: 85%;
    }

    .headline {
        font-size: 240px;
        letter-spacing: 40px;
    }

    .about-dr-alex {
        font-size: 30px;
        top: 220px;
        left: 40px;
    }

    .barcode {
        width: 200px;
    }

    .specialist-plastic-surgeon {
        font-size: 25px;
        top: 100px;
        right: 40px;
    }

    .crafting-individual,
    .solutions {
        font-size: 25px;
        line-height: 30px;
    }

    .crafting-individual {
        top: 250px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .solutions {
        top: 310px;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .crafting-individual-solutions:hover .crafting-individual,
    .crafting-individual-solutions:hover .solutions {
        padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    }

    .global-network-of-expertise>a,
    .global-network-of-expertise>a:active,
    .global-network-of-expertise>a:visited {
        font-size: 25px;
        line-height: 28px;
        right: 40px;
        top: 400px;
    }

    .areas-of-expertise>a,
    .areas-of-expertise>a:active,
    .areas-of-expertise>a:visited {
        font-size: 25px;
        right: 40px;
        top: 520px;
    }

    .commitment-and-family {
        top: 580px;
        right: 40px;
    }
}
```

Html code:

```
<div class="home-page">
    <div class="background">
        <h1 class="headline">LANDAU</h1>
        <a [routerLink]="['/about']">
            <h3 class="about-dr-alex">ABOUT DR ALEX</h3>
        </a>
        <img src="assets/images/home/Home.png" class="person">
        <img src="assets/images/home/Home-barcode.png" class="barcode">

        <div class="links">
            <div class="specialist-plastic-surgeon">SPECIALIST<br/>PLASTIC<br/>SURGEON</div>
            <div class="crafting-individual-solutions">
                <a [routerLink]="['/crafting-individual-solutions']">
                    <span class="crafting-individual">Crafting Individual</span> 
                    <span class="solutions">Solutions</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="global-network-of-expertise">
                <a [routerLink]="['/global-network-of-expertise']">
                    a Global<br/> Network<br/> <span class="of-expertise">of expertise</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="areas-of-expertise">
                <a [routerLink]="['/areas-of-expertise']">
                    Areas of Expertise
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="commitment-and-family">
                <a [routerLink]="['/commitment-and-family']">
                    <span class="commitment">Commitment</span>
                    <span class="and">&</span>
                    <span class="family">Family</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to show only the code you tried, instead of all the code (so readers can locate and debug the error). Just a recommendation though!

Comment: Hey man! I added the entire code to my home page. Honestly dont know if it will help.

Comment: Unfortunately, the layout is not responsive and is designed for a huge screen. I get the same result on my laptop. Back to the drawing board, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah, my screen is kinda big. I'm yet to add a mobile version. :(

Comment: You really have to design for all screens at once. (It's easy enough to do, as you can test everything by narrowing the browser width to get a good idea of how everything works.) Designing for a large screen, and using things like absolute positioning, is setting yourself up for a nightmare scenario.

Comment: Yeah I think what's happening is my client scaled his pc to 150% (windows scaling) which affected the website. Maybe that's why it's using the incorrect device width, maybe its using lower that 1920 when scaled to 150% and I don't have that in place yet. My screen is scaled to 100%, that's why it looks correct on my screen. I was able to replicate the issue by scaling it to 150%. Do you think there's an easy fix for this? Or I gotta design the smaller screens first?

Comment: I'd definitely recommend staying away from absolute positioning as much as possible because it will create issues upon issues the moment you try and make the webpage any bit responsive.

Comment: The design is just calls for it. lol